# Mysql - how to sort the date format with am/pm

Tags: mysql, sql

Please check the query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CAST( CONCAT( table.date,  " ", table.time ) ) ,  '%p' ) 
FROM table AS table

Error:
[hash]1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), '%p') FROM exp_visitorsday as vd LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2
```

I have tried this query in following cases.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CAST( CONCAT( table.date,  " ", table.time ) as datetimecol ) as datetimecol,  '%p' ) 
FROM table AS table

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CAST( CONCAT( table.date,  " ", table.time ) as datetimecol ),  '%p' ) 
FROM table AS table
```

Sample data:

```
table.date => 01-08-2013
table.time => 10:00 AM
```

How to do query? What's a problem in this query?

Comment: `CAST( CONCAT( table.date,  " ", table.time ) )`... cast to what?

Comment: Thanks Joachim. Cast into a time. I made a mistake in query. I'll change and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT( 
                                    CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", -1), "-",  
                                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", 2), "-", -1), "-", 
                                    SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", 1), " ", 
                                    IF( SUBSTRING_INDEX( "10:00 PM", " ", -1) = "AM", 
                                                SUBSTRING_INDEX( "10:00 AM", " ", 1),  
                                                CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( "10:00 AM", " ", 1), ":", 1) + 12, ":", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( "10:00 AM", " ", 1), ":", -1))  )) , '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') AS datformat ) AS tmp
ORDER BY tmp.datformat;
```

Explain:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", 1); #Day
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", 2), "-", -1);#Month
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( "01-08-2013", "-", -1); #Year
```

Comment: Thanks GaCon. I have used this query to do. But I failed. Can you please check it out?

Comment: Thanks GaCon. Query is fine. I had an invalid data with db. Perfect!!!...Good Job..Go ahead!!